# Appcelerator app not available on ios 10

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have developed a app for iOS. And during local test and testing through testflight I expirence no problems at all.
The app works both on iOS 10 and iOS 11.

But when the app have been published the app update is only available on iOS 11.

Titanium GA.7.1.1
XCode 9.4 (9F1027a)

The app is unable to be installed on Model MD522KN/A running 10.3.3 (14G60)

If i revert to Titanium GA 6.0.3 the app works as intented on this device, but not when iOS is version 11 and onward.

Do Titanium GA.7.1.1 not support iOS 10, or might I have missed something?

Please help.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>dk.tankegang.thistedvf.vpp</id>
    <name>Thistedvf</name>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <publisher>supporttankegang</publisher>
    <url>http://www.tankegang.dk</url>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <copyright>2017 by supporttankegang</copyright>
    <icon>Defaulticon.png</icon>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>44abb7f8-6cbb-495f-9aaa-47d2ff11e589</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
                <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Can we use your contacts?</string>
                <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Can we use your camera?</string>
                <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Can we use your calendar?</string>
                <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Can we use your photolibrary?</string>
                <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Can we use your microphone?</string>
                <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Can we use your microphone?</string>
                <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <modules>
        <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
        <module platform="iphone" version="1.8">com.acktie.mobile.ios.barcode</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">false</target>
        <target device="ipad">true</target>
        <target device="iphone">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>7.1.1.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <property name="appc-app-id" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-authbase-url-development" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
    <property name="acs-base-url-development" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
    <property name="acs-oauth-secret-development" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-oauth-key-development" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-username-development" type="string">appc_app_user_dev</property>
    <property name="acs-password-development" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-authbase-url-production" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
    <property name="acs-base-url-production" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
    <property name="acs-oauth-secret-production" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-oauth-key-production" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string"></property>
    <property name="acs-username-production" type="string">appc_app_user</property>
    <property name="acs-password-production" type="string"></property>
    <property name="appc-org-id" type="string"></property>
    <property name="appc-creator-user-id" type="string"></property>
</ti:app>
```

Comment: it still supports iOS 9, what have you configured in tiapp as minimum version?

Comment: I have added the trap.xml. I do not recall adding a minimum version. But I might have overlooked something. Please se my edit.

Comment: don't share all your API keys.

Comment: Also, https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-src-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-min-ios-ver